# python fabric running remote bash scripts

Tags: python, fabric

I have been working on python fabric module.
Currently I have written a fabfile to invoke a remote bash script on a remote server. However id doesnt seem to work.

My fabfile looks like this:-

```
from fabric.api import *

env.hosts=['some-host']
env.user="root"

def deploy():
    run("/home/hduser/test.sh")
```

It executes test.sh on the remote host.The script is a simple bash script which looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "fabric works" >> out.txt
```

However even though fabric returns a 0 success code I cannot 
    see out.txt file appended with fabric works

Am I missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking in wrong directory, out.txt file is probably in the home directory of root.